# How to change the "User License" type for customer portal users using a script?

Tags: customer-portal, licenses

We want to move a large number of customer portal users (users who self-register via a pre-existing Contact record) from one "User License" type to another. But I note that in the User edit page the "User License" field is not editable (whereas it is for other license types) and in any case as thousands of users are involved we would like to automate the process.

Can this be done via an Apex script? Or can this be done via a Salesforce support request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This Knowledge Article [User license conversion when migrating from portal to communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000232583&type=1) covers the transitions that are simple:

> An administrator can change the license type and profile on the user
>   record.

and the transitions that when attempted result in the error message:

> cannot upgrade from or downgrade to LPU

and so require this disruptive process to accomplish:

> An administrator must disable the contact as a Customer User  and then
>   re-enable as a Customer User to create a new user record and associate
>   it with the new license.

This [Migrating from Portals to
Communities](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/5/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_portal_to_community_migration_cheatsheet.pdf) cheatsheet includes a table that can be used to predict what is an upgrade/downgrade.

Comment: Disappointing that's there's no way to mass change the user license type, say from Authenticated Website to Customer Community.